# Tasks combine result and continue

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task

I have 16 tasks doing the same job, each of them return an array. I want to combine the results in pairs  and do same job until I have only one task. I don't know what is the best way to do this.

```
public static IComparatorNetwork[] Prune(IComparatorNetwork[] nets, int numTasks)
    {
        var tasks = new Task[numTasks];
        var netsPerTask = nets.Length/numTasks;
        var start = 0;
        var concurrentSet = new ConcurrentBag<IComparatorNetwork>();
        
        for(var i = 0; i  < numTasks; i++)
        {
            IComparatorNetwork[] taskNets;
            if (i == numTasks - 1)
            {
                taskNets = nets.Skip(start).ToArray();                 
            }
            else
            {
                taskNets = nets.Skip(start).Take(netsPerTask).ToArray();
            }

            start += netsPerTask;
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var pruner = new Pruner();
                concurrentSet.AddRange(pruner.Prune(taskNets));
            });
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        if(numTasks > 1)
        {
            return Prune(concurrentSet.ToArray(), numTasks/2);
        }

        return concurrentSet.ToArray();
    }
```

Right now I am waiting for all tasks to complete then I repeat with half of the tasks until I have only one. I would like to not have to wait for all on each iteration. I am very new with parallel programming probably the approach is bad.
The code I am trying to parallelize is the following:

```
public IComparatorNetwork[] Prune(IComparatorNetwork[] nets)
    {
        var result = new List<IComparatorNetwork>();

        for (var i = 0; i < nets.Length; i++) 
        {
            var isSubsumed = false;

            for (var index = result.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
            {
                var n = result[index];

                if (nets[i].IsSubsumed(n))
                {
                    isSubsumed = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (n.IsSubsumed(nets[i]))
                {
                    result.Remove(n);
                }
            }

            if (!isSubsumed) 
            {
                result.Add(nets[i]);
            }
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }`
```

Comment: What is this code trying to do? Whatever it is, you don't need all that code. It's quite possible a PLINQ or `Parallel.ForEach` query with the default Degree-of-Parallelism would be faster. PLINQ partitions the data into as many partitions as there are cores and uses one worker tasks to process each partition. The `Sum` or `Aggregate` calls at the end of a `PLINQ` query will combine the partial results and produce the final results

Comment: The code gets an array and it performs a comparison element by element, it returns a new array with the elements that fulfill a condition (the result of the prune). The problem is that I should compare all elements. I will add the non parallel code as example.

Comment: Are you sure that the `IsSubsumed` method of the class that implements the `IComparatorNetwork` interface is thread-safe? Because it is possible to be called by multiple threads concurrently. Unless I am not understanding your code, which is quite possible. My general feeling is that your code has quite a few interdependencies, which makes it a not very attractive candidate for parallelization. The overhead of the synchronization may neutralize completely the benefits of parallelism (the parallelized version may be slower than the single-thread one).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The code in the question partitions the objects into separate groups, with no objects being in multiple groups, and each group is then processed by a single thread.  They are then re-partitioned and re-combined into new groups only after they all done being combined.  I agree the code in the question doesn't do the clearest job in demonstrating that it's safe in that way, but it looks like it does accomplish it.

Comment: @Servy yeap, after seeing your answer (great answer btw!) it is now clearer what the OP is trying to do. I am not sure about the method `IsSubsumed` though. It looks innocent, but my gut feeling is that it may have side effects. In which case the correctness of the algorithm is at stake.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I strongly suspect it has no side effects, based on it's name.  It's trying to figure out if one object is entirely represented by another, and if so, it's no longer needed.  That said, even if it did have side effects, since no net has the method called on it while another worker could be working on it, it could only be a problem if if mutated the object *asynchronously after it returned*, and there's no reason at all to assume it's doing that given the code as written.  For example pretend they're all date ranges and it's asking if one date range is contained in another.

Comment: @Servy yeap, most probably you are right, and I am concerned about a non-issue.

Comment: Yes, the code does exactly what @Servy said. It discards nets that are equivalent to others. It is thread safe and with the accepted solution the tests are green. Nevertheless I guess I will have to change it because with the AggregateInParallel the performance gain is not big enough I am only getting around a 25% improvement. And this method is the performance critical one because the subsume operation is computationally expensive.

Comment: @JaviGonzálezGarcía You spend a lot of time re-creating collections, which you can avoid.  Prune can accept an IEnumerable, not an array, since all it's doing is iterating the items, and you could return the list (or even an IReadOnlyList if you want to prevent future mutation to it) to avoid that copy.  Even if the thing calling this large scale prune needs an array, it can turn the results into an array easily enough without forcing the internals of the method to do it over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're fundamentally doing here is aggregating values, but in parallel.  Fortunately, PLINQ already has an implementation of Aggregate that works in parallel.  So in your case you can simply wrap each element in the original array in its own one element array, and then your `Prune` operation is able to combine any two arrays of nets into a new single array.

```
public static IComparatorNetwork[] Prune(IComparatorNetwork[] nets)
{
    return nets.Select(net => new[] { net })
        .AsParallel()
        .Aggregate((a, b) => new Pruner().Prune(a.Concat(b).ToArray()));
}
```

I'm not super knowledgeable about the internals of their aggregate method, but I would imagine it's likely pretty good and doesn't spend a lot of time waiting unnecessarily.  But, if you want to write your own, so that you can be sure the workers are always pulling in new work as soon as their is new work, here is my own implementation.  Feel free to compare the two in your specific situation to see which performs best for your needs.  Note that PLINQ is configurable in many ways, feel free to experiment with other configurations to see what works best for your situation.

```
public static T AggregateInParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, T, T> function, int numTasks)
{
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
    foreach (var value in values)
        queue.Enqueue(value);
    if (!queue.Any())
        return default(T);  //Consider throwing or doing something else here if the sequence is empty

    (T, T)? GetFromQueue()
    {
        lock (queue)
        {
            if (queue.Count >= 2)
            {
                return (queue.Dequeue(), queue.Dequeue());
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, numTasks)
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var pair = GetFromQueue();
            while (pair != null)
            {
                var result = function(pair.Value.Item1, pair.Value.Item2);
                lock (queue)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(result);
                }
                pair = GetFromQueue();
            }
        }))
        .ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    return queue.Dequeue();
}
```

And the calling code for this version would look like:

```
public static IComparatorNetwork[] Prune2(IComparatorNetwork[] nets)
{
    return nets.Select(net => new[] { net })
        .AggregateInParallel((a, b) => new Pruner().Prune(a.Concat(b).ToArray()), nets.Length / 2);
}
```

As mentioned in comments, you can make the pruner's `Prune` method much more efficient by having it accept two collections, not just one, and only comparing items from each collection with the other, knowing that all items from the same collection will not subsume any others from that collection.  This makes the method not only much shorter, simpler, and easier to understand, but also removes a sizeable portion of the expensive comparisons.  A few minor adaptations can also greatly reduce the number of intermediate collections created.

```
public static IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork> Prune(IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork> first, IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork> second)
{
    var firstItemsNotSubsumed = first.Where(outerNet => !second.Any(innerNet => outerNet.IsSubsumed(innerNet)));
    var secondItemsNotSubsumed = second.Where(outerNet => !first.Any(innerNet => outerNet.IsSubsumed(innerNet)));
    return firstItemsNotSubsumed.Concat(secondItemsNotSubsumed).ToList();
}
```

With the the calling code just needs minor adaptations to ensure the types match up and that you pass in both collections rather than concatting them first.

```
public static IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork> Prune(IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork> nets)
{
    return nets.Select(net => (IReadOnlyList<IComparatorNetwork>)new[] { net })
        .AggregateInParallel((a, b) => Pruner.Prune(a, b), nets.Count / 2);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! That's what I was looking for. Btw your aggregate function is much faster than the linq one.

Comment: @JaviGonzálezGarcía I know many many years ago I was under the impression that the .NET version performed quite poorly, but I didn't know how much it had been improved since which is why I at least mentioned the .NET version.

Comment: Great answer, upvoted. Just a general note about starting multiple workers and awaiting all of them to complete: In case of exceptions each exception kills one worker, and the processing continues with a reduced degree of parallelism. If you are unlucky to have exactly `numTasks - 1` early exceptions, the last standing worker will slowly process all elements alone, until the exceptions are finally surfaced. A more polished implementation could address this problem by terminating gracefully the whole operation in case of an exception in any of the workers. Much like the `Parallel.ForEach` does.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, the problem is there are many possible things you might want to do in the event of an exception, so no matter what it'll need to be adjusted to suit the desired behavior.  That said, in your example case any workers that throw also aren't putting the items they pulled or any results back into the queue, so if only one worker didn't throw then there will only be one result, and so it'll finish without having any more work to process.

Comment: I am not sure that I get the argument. Lets say that you have 100 nets to process, and 16 workers, and 15 of the workers die on the first invocation of `function`. This means that 30 nets (15 pairs) have been dequeued and lost, and the last standing worker will process the remaining 70 nets alone. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The code specifically starts n/2 workers (which is what the OP requested in the question), which is why that assertion holds.

Comment: Oh, you are right, now I see it. This makes this specific application of the `AggregateInParallel` method not susceptible to this problem. But the problem still exists in general. Btw starting `nets.Length / 2` tasks at once means that -for any non-trivial number of nets- the `ThreadPool` is going to be saturated pretty badly. Essentially the whole operation is going to be throttled by the `ThreadPool` availability.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sure.  I imagine the thread pool is likely going to do a better job of determining the appropriate number of threads to run than anything I'd whip up for an SO answer.  It's designed for that after all.

Comment: Actually the `ThreadPool` algorithm seems to be pretty dump. Which is a good thing, because you don't want the tools you use to outsmart you. What it does is to create new threads on demand until it reaches the `SetMinThreads` threshold. After that threshold has been reached, it waits for 500 msec for an already running job to complete, and if this doesn't happen it starts a new thread and assigns a queued job to it. So if you schedule many long running jobs at once, you'll see the number of threads incrementing steadily every half a second.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias But it won't exceed what the CPU can process in parallel unless you're adjusting it's settings manually, so it's not going to create more workers than are useful unless someone is doing something that they probably shouldn't be doing.

Comment: The default `ThreadPool.GetMinThreads` value for PCs is near (or equal) to the logical processors of the machine (AFAIK server machines have larger defaults). So as soon as the 500 msec injection algorithm kicks in, you are already in oversubscription territory. Which is a logical compromise if you think about it. It has to do something in order to ensure forward progress in case the existing threads are stuck, but it shouldn't do much otherwise essentially it would not be a thread-pool any more.

Comment: I think my post was misunderstanding I didn't want nets/2 tasks it's only that the way I had thought about it on each step I need half of the workers. Also correct me if I am wrong but I suspect that this solution is making my code to repeat subsume operations already performed. Because at each step we apply a concat and recheck all the list of subsume test applying the subsume test in both ways (is not symmetrical) but lots of them were already checked by previous worker. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JaviGonzálezGarcía You're not wrong, although the code in the question behaves the same.  If the collections are not being reduced much, then that's duplicating a lot of effort and you'd probably be better off just performing the operation sequentially on the whole thing.  If you're removing lots of items, then the later checks having way less items to check against improve things a lot by the time you get to the last step.  Given that your original code choose the approach it did, I assumed the data you were working with involved lots of items being removed.

Comment: @JaviGonzálezGarcía To improve your prune method you can simply have the pruner accept two sequences, rather than one, and then know that all of the items in each sequence cannot be subsumed by any other in that sequence, so you instead only need to compare items from each sequence to those from the other.  Then you can just not concat the sequences together before going into the pruner.

Comment: How can I do what you propose? I had thought that I need to first apply the prune to batches of the array. So with this I will generate for example 12 lists that have no subsumptions in between their elements. And later I can create a modification of the prune method that checks the subsumption only in one direction, receiving 2 lists as you propose, and crosscheck this lists. But I don't know if there is a way to do this without having to wait for all tasks to end in each iteration.

Comment: @JaviGonzálezGarcía It wouldn't change anything about how the aggregation function works.  You'd only change the Prune method.  Rather than accepting one collection, and comparing every item in it to every other item, you could accept two collections.  Go through every item in the first and remove those subsumed by the second, then go through the second and remove those subsumed by the first.  That avoids comparing every item with the items from its own original collection (because those will all have been checked in earlier prune calls when that portion was combined).