# Partition: How to add a wait after every partition

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, rate-limiting

I have an API that has accepts 20 requests per minute, after that, I need to wait for 1 minute before querying it. I have a list of items (usually 1000+) whose details I need to query from the API, my thought was I could use `Partitioner` to partition my list into 20 items/requests but soon I realized the `Partitioner` does not work like that, my 2nd thought was adding a `delay` in the partition but that too is a bad idea, from my understanding it adds a delay after every request which is not needed, instead, I need a delay after every `Partition`. Below is my code:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<V>> ForEachAsync<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    int degreeOfParallelism, Func<T, Task<V>> body, CancellationToken token,
    [Optional] int delay)
{
    var whenAll = await Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(degreeOfParallelism)
        select Task.Run(async delegate {
            var allResponses = new List<V>();
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                {
                    allResponses.Add(await body(partition.Current));
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay));
                }
            return allResponses;
        }, token));
    return whenAll.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Related: [How to execute tasks in parallel but not more than N tasks per T seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208044/how-to-execute-tasks-in-parallel-but-not-more-than-n-tasks-per-t-seconds)

Comment: Does the duration of the requests counts towards the requests-per-minute policy? In other words are you allowed to *start* 20 requests per minute (independently of their duration), or you must wait for a minute after the *completion* of the 20 previous requests?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias no it does not, what matters is; 20 calls per minute.

Comment: Related: [Add delay to parallel API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519475/add-delay-to-parallel-api-call) (Polly)

Comment: As a side note, be aware that your current implementation of `ForEachAsync` (which is probably a modified version of the last `ForEachAsync` in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/) article), handles exceptions in a non-ideal way. The reasons are explained in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265723/tasks-combine-result-and-continue/64267212#64267212) answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I have eliminated the `ForEachAsync`, the `RateLimiter` in your previous comment seems to work, I am currently testing it and will get back.

Comment: You mean the `RateLimiter` class from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519475/add-delay-to-parallel-api-call/64520626#64520626)? That's a fairly complicated piece of code. It's beyond my capabilities to review it and confirm its correctness.

Comment: Another related question: [Simple way to rate limit HttpClient requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493925/simple-way-to-rate-limit-httpclient-requests)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a `RateLimiter` class that you could use in order to limit the frequency of the asynchronous operations. It is a simpler implementation of the `RateLimiter` class that is found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519475/add-delay-to-parallel-api-call/64520626#64520626) answer.

```
/// <summary>
/// Limits the number of workers that can access a resource, during the specified
/// time span.
/// </summary>
public class RateLimiter
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeUnit;

    public RateLimiter(int maxActionsPerTimeUnit, TimeSpan timeUnit)
    {
        if (maxActionsPerTimeUnit < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxActionsPerTimeUnit));
        if (timeUnit < TimeSpan.Zero || timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds > Int32.MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(timeUnit));
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxActionsPerTimeUnit, maxActionsPerTimeUnit);
        _timeUnit = timeUnit;
    }

    public async Task WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        // Schedule the release of the semaphore using a Timer.
        // Use the newly created Timer object as the state object, to prevent GC.
        // Handle the unlikely case that the _timeUnit is invalid.
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new(_ => _semaphore.Release());
        try { timer.Change(_timeUnit, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan); }
        catch { _semaphore.Release(); throw; }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<string> urls = GetUrls();

using var rateLimiter = new RateLimiter(20, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));

string[] documents = await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(async url =>
{
    await rateLimiter.WaitAsync();
    return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}));
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CE6UJv).

The [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) is constructed with [this specific constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor#system-threading-timer-ctor(system-threading-timercallback)) to prevent it from being garbage collected until it fires, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962172/why-does-a-system-timers-timer-survive-gc-but-not-system-threading-timer/19617215#19617215) by Nick H.

**Note:** This implementation is slightly leaky in the sense that it creates internally disposable `System.Threading.Timer` objects, that are not disposed when you are finished using the `RateLimiter`. Any active timers will prevent the `RateLimiter` from being garbage collected until these timers have fired their callback. Also the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) is not disposed [as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467373/should-we-implement-idisposable-if-one-member-is-idisposable). These are minor flaws, that are unlikely to affect a program that creates only a handful of `RateLimiter`s. In case you intend to create a lot of them, you could take a look at the [3rd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65829971/3) of this answer, that features a disposable `RateLimiter` based on the `Task.Delay` method.

---

Here is an alternative implementation of the `RateLimiter` class, more complex, which is based on the [`Environment.TickCount64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64) property instead of a `SemaphoreSlim`. It has the advantage that it doesn't create fire-and-forget timers in the background. The disadvantages are that the `WaitAsync` method does not support a `CancellationToken` argument, and that the probability of bugs is higher because of the complexity.

```
public class RateLimiter
{
    private readonly Queue<long> _queue;
    private readonly int _maxActionsPerTimeUnit;
    private readonly int _timeUnitMilliseconds;

    public RateLimiter(int maxActionsPerTimeUnit, TimeSpan timeUnit)
    {
        // Arguments validation omitted
        _queue = new Queue<long>();
        _maxActionsPerTimeUnit = maxActionsPerTimeUnit;
        _timeUnitMilliseconds = checked((int)timeUnit.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public Task WaitAsync()
    {
        int delayMilliseconds = 0;
        lock (_queue)
        {
            long currentTimestamp = Environment.TickCount64;
            while (_queue.Count > 0 && _queue.Peek() < currentTimestamp)
            {
                _queue.Dequeue();
            }
            if (_queue.Count >= _maxActionsPerTimeUnit)
            {
                long refTimestamp = _queue
                    .Skip(_queue.Count - _maxActionsPerTimeUnit).First();
                delayMilliseconds = checked((int)(refTimestamp - currentTimestamp));
                Debug.Assert(delayMilliseconds >= 0);
                if (delayMilliseconds < 0) delayMilliseconds = 0; // Just in case
            }
            _queue.Enqueue(currentTimestamp + delayMilliseconds
                + _timeUnitMilliseconds);
        }
        if (delayMilliseconds == 0) return Task.CompletedTask;
        return Task.Delay(delayMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works amazingly well and simplifies my work, no need for partitioning. Thank you.